# How to query different post types in specific order?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

I have 3 posts types, `articles`, `news` and `tips`. On the home page I want to query 20 posts in this order:

```
article, article, news, news, tip, ...// same order again until 20
```

If I use a custom query like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => array('articles', 'news', 'tips'),
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
));
```

I get 20 items but how to order them? Would it be possible to make 3 different queries and then merge the results?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely could use three different queries and then merge them.

```
// Query 7 items per Custom Post Type.
// A, A, N, N, T, T will result in 8 x A, 6 x N and 6 x T.
$atricles = new WP_Query( 'post_type=article&posts_per_page=8' ); // A
$news     = new WP_Query( 'post_type=news&posts_per_page=6' ); // N
$tips     = new WP_Query( 'post_type=tips&posts_per_page=6' ); // T

// Assign new array keys to the queried posts
$stp = 0; $key = 0; $arr = array();
foreach ( $articles->posts as $post_obj ) { $key++; $arr[$stp + $key] = $post_obj; if ( $key === 2 ) { $stp += 6; $key = 0; } }
$articles->posts = $arr;

$stp = 2; $key = 0; $arr = array();
foreach ( $news->posts as $post_obj ) { $key++; $arr[$stp + $key] = $post_obj; if ( $key === 2 ) { $stp += 6; $key = 0; } }
$news->posts = $arr;

$stp = 4; $key = 0; $arr = array();
foreach ( $tips->posts as $post_obj ) { $key++; $arr[$stp + $key] = $post_obj; if ( $key === 2 ) { $stp += 6; $key = 0; } }
$tips->posts = $arr;

// Modify one object to contain all Posts
// Use the + array union operator to preserve the array keys
$articles->posts = $articles->posts + $news->posts + $tips->posts;

// Sort the array by keys.
ksort( $articles->posts );

// Don't forget to "reset" the post_count variable in the modified object.
// This way you will have 20 posts instead of the queried 8 (in this case).
$articles->post_count += $news->post_count;
$articles->post_count += $tips->post_count;

// Use the modified result object for the loop
while ( $articles->has_posts() ):
  $articles->the_post();

  // Do your stuff with it :-)
endwhile;
```

This may look like a very odd way to do this, but this way you can use *the loop* and preserve the option to use *pagination*. Although a direct query to the database can be quicker I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a modified version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275574/wordpress-ordering-multiples-post-types) :

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby');

$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => array('articles', 'news', 'tips'),
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
));

remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby');
```

where

```
function custom_posts_orderby($orderby) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->posts .".post_type ASC,".$wpdb->posts .".post_date DESC";
}
```

So the posts are first ordered by `post_type` (asc) and then by `post_date` (desc).